# Pytest monkeypatch not working on flask view function

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest

Suppose we have the following Flask view function to test. Specifically, we want to mock `create_foo()` as it writes to the filesystem.

```
# proj_root/some_project/views.py
from some_project import APP
from some_project.libraries.foo import create_foo

@APP.route('/run', methods=['POST']
def run():
    bar = create_foo()
    return 'Running'
```

Now we want to write a unit test for `run()` with the call to `create_foo()` mocked to avoid creating unnecessary files.

```
# proj_root/tests/test_views.py
from some_project import some_project

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    some_project.APP.config['TESTING'] = True
    with some_project.APP.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_run(client, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('some_project.libraries.foo.create_foo', lambda: None)
    response = client.post('/run')
    assert b'Running' in response.data
```

It seems that this approach should work even with the named `create_foo` import. The tests all pass, however the original code of `create_foo` is clearly being executed as a new file in the filesystem is created each time the test suite is run. What am I missing? I suspect it has something to do with the named imports based on some related questions but I'm not sure.

Comment: the code shown above is not valid syntax for `monkeypatch`. as the docs state it is of the signature `monkeypatch.setattr(obj, name, value, raising=True)` you're missing an argument

Comment: @aws_apprentice that's actually not true. See the note in the `setattr` docs [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch). I successfully use this syntax in the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct monkeypatch is:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('some_project.views.create_foo', lambda: None)
```

The reason for this is pretty well explained [here](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/).